# Vertically aligning part of content within list items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align only part of the content in my list items.

[Here](https://www.screencast.com/t/atCx5IwZgI) is a link to the screenshot.

The "Current" picture is my progress so far, and the "Solution picture is what I am trying to achieve"

If you take a close look at the list items you'll notice that in the "Solution", part of the list items is vertically aligned.

Could someone please explain how I would be able to do this?

Here is my CSS

```
#middleText {
  float: right;
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
    <ul>
      <li><strong>Distance</strong> <span id="middleText">40 miles</span></li>
      <li><strong>Elevation Gain</strong> <span id="middleText">10,779 feet</span></li>
      <li><strong>Permit Required</strong> <span id="middleText">Yes</span></li>
      <li><strong>Difficulty Rating</strong><span id="middleText"> 4 (strenuous)</span></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: I think your id middleTexts should be classes. It is not permissible to have several uses of the same I’d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with grid:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start;
}

li {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>&#9900;<strong>Distance</strong> <span id="middleText">40 miles</span></li>
  <li>&#9900;<strong>Elevation Gain</strong> <span id="middleText">10,779 feet</span></li>
  <li>&#9900;<strong>Permit Required</strong> <span id="middleText">Yes</span></li>
  <li>&#9900;<strong>Difficulty Rating</strong><span id="middleText"> 4 (strenuous)</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works, but then the bullet points disappear. How do I get them to show up?

Comment: Yes they disappear because of grid. You can add HTML symbol  ˙&#8226;˙ or other ones if you like . I updated answer, take a look pls

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HTML table without its border to achieve the "solution".

```html
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td> Distance </td>
<td> 40 miles </td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Elevation Gain </td>
<td>10,779 feet </td></tr>
<tr>
<td> Permit Required</td>
<td> Yes </td></tr>
<tr>
<td> Difficulty Rating</td>
<td> 4(s..) </td></tr>
</table>
```

Use CSS accordingly to match the styles.